# Flask View Testing General and with Subdomains

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on testing the views that I have for a Flask application and I'm having some issues. I use a csrf token for my form submissions and I also use subdomains for logging in and I was wondering how to test for that as well. If anyone has any experience or could give me an example or some direction, I would appreciate it because I've already gone through all of the guides and documentation I could fine.

Below is what I'm trying to test and the test I'm running.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        #acts as redirect, but with subdomain
        return redirect_subdomain('login', request.url, request.form['subdomain'])

    except OrganizationDoesNotExistException:
        return render_template('login.html', subdomain=False)

return render_template('login.html', subdomain=False)
```

These are the tests I'm running just to get started. It only accepts a subdomain (organization) that will be used to redirect the user to the subdomain specific login, which works, I just want to know how to write tests for the future:

```
def test_login(self):
    rv = self.login('test')
    print(rv.data.decode('utf-8'))
    pass


def login(self, organization):
    return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
        organization=organization
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

I know these are basic tests and don't really test much, but I still get errors and I want to know how to go about testing views in general and when there are subdomains involved, like in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to create unittests for a flask app using subdomain routing, the `test_client()` function can be used.  For this to work, you will need to set the  `allow_subdomain_redirects` attribute on the `test_client` object to `True`.

Here is an example test case for a flask app using subdomain routing.

```
import yourapp
import unittest

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = yourapp.app.test_client()
        self.app.allow_subdomain_redirects = True

    def test_request(self):
        r = self.app.get('http://subdomain.domain.com/route/', query_string='key=value')
        self.assertEquals(r.data, known_result)
```

Comment: @YakovL I think that you meant to post this comment to the OP's question. I did not actually ask any question in this post, so I do not understand why I would need to "bring more people at least willing to answer". Either way I attempted to clarify my response.            
Also, what is not good about saying "Try to make a test **case** similar to this:" (emphasis mine)  followed by the code for a test case?  Can you please clarify what is lacking from my answer?

Comment: yeap, sorry, I wasn't attentive enough because of tiredness. No need to do smth about your answer, my bad